# Фильтрование по цвету

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется `DataGridView` в него приходят значения из базы, где при определённом сроке ячейка выделяется в красный цвет.

Но со временем база сильно разрослась, и потребовалась  фильтр по цвету
На одном из форумов нашёл

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridview1.Rows)
   {
      if(r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
      {

      }
   }
}
```

Но он сильно грузит процесс и нифига не работает, да и не врубился куда выводить результат.

**UPD**

```
     if(datagridview.rows[e.rowindex].Cells["Срок_до"].value !=null &&((DateTime)datagridview.rows[e.rowindex].Cells["Срок_до"].valu‌​e).CompareTo(datetim‌​e <0) 
            {
               datagridview.rows[e.Rowindex].defaultcellstyle = color.red
            }
    for (var index = 0; index<datagridview.Columns.Count; ++index)
    {
    var formattedvalue = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell[index].FormattedValue;

    if(formattedvalue==null) continue;

    var str = formattedvalue.ToString().ToLower();

    if(str!="удален")
    {
      if(str=="неограничен")
         datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
       datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

**Данные из базы**

```
Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dist", new MySqlConnection(Connect.ToString()));
    Adapter.Fill(dt);
    datagrid.DataSource = dt;
```

**UPD**
Сейчас фильтруется так:

```
var dataview = new DataView(dt)
{
   RowFilter = $"Срок_до < '{datetime}' AND Комментарии = '' AND Статус_отработки = ''"
}
```

Но есть загвоздка так как присутствует 3 цвета и нужно сделать так что бы показало только 1 цвет красный.

**UPD**

Добавил картинку[image: Вот так сейчас, белым там конфиденциальная информация]

Прошу оказать помощь)

Comment: WinForms? Добавьте тег. Нужно не цвет ячейки проверять, а значение в привязанной коллекции или вообще сортировку делать в базе.

Comment: `Но со временем база сильно разрослась, и потребовалась сортировка по цвету...` Какая связь между размером БД и сортировкой по цвету?

Comment: @sp7 по времени, когда наступает определённая дата он окрашивает в красный цвет. If(datagrid.rows[e.rowindex].Cells["Срок_до"].value !=null &&((DateTime)datagrid.rows[e.rowindex].Cells["Срок_до"].value).CompareTo(datetime <0) datagrid.rows[e.Rowindex].defaultcellstyle = color.red

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях, переместите его в вопрос, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/675993/edit). И уточните, как данные попадают в грид: вручную заносятся или с помощью привязки (binding)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Внёс изменения как приходят данные из базы

Comment: [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) и [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) - это два разных контрола. Чтобы читающие ваш код не путались, давайте точное имя своему компоненту.

Comment: @Павел то есть вы хотите оставить только необработанные строчки? для которых пуст и комментарий и статус обработки? если да, то просто добавьте эти условия в фильтр.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Сделал как вы предложили. но он показал не все значения

Comment: @Павел показал не все значения значит убрал лишнее?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper да, в общем он не показывает со значением в базе null но если стоит просто пусто он отображает нормально

Comment: значит нужно добавить еще проверку на `null`

Comment: вот такой фильтр попробуйте - `$"Срок_до < '{datetime}' AND Isnull(Комментарии, '') = '' AND Isnull(Статус_отработки, '') = ''"`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Работает, большое спасибо тебе, дай бог тебе здоровья)

Comment: спасибо, рад помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректный фильтр:

```
var dataview = new DataView(dt)
{
   RowFilter = $"Срок_до < '{datetime}' AND Isnull(Комментарии, '') = '' AND Isnull(Статус_отработки, '') = ''"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Подсветка значения цветом - это работа представления.

Навесим на `DataGridView` обработчик события `CellFormatting` и напишем в нём следующий код:

```
private void DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) // индекс нужной колонки
    {
        if (e.Value != null && (DateTime)e.Value < dateTime)
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

В итоге нужные ячейки выделены цветом.

Теперь сортировка. Это уже работа слоя данных, не следует её делать в самом гриде.

Вообще, она автоматически выполняется, когда пользователь кликнет по заголовку (хедеру) колонки грида. Но если хочется сделать сортировку по нажатию своей кнопки, то это делается элементарно благодаря привязке данных. Так как данные помещены в `DataTable`, его возможности и используем:

```
private void SortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Time"; // имя колонки, по которой сортируем
}
```

Просто берём `DataView` и используем его свойство `Sort`. Обратите внимание, что при этом у колонки грида появляется стрелочка - значок сортировки.

По умолчанию сортировка осуществляется по возрастанию. Если нужно сделать по убыванию, пишем:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Time desc";
```

При желании можно осуществлять сортировку по нескольким столбцам одновременно, достаточно указать их через запятую:

```
"Time, Id"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он мне не очень подходит мне нужно что бы убрались все ячейки кроме красных. На подобии 
 DataView,RowFilter

Comment: @Павел - так в чём проблема? Вот и напишите в `RowFilter` условие сравнения с датой.

Comment: Что то я не могу догнать с условием.

Comment: так он как бы работает RowFilter = $"Срок_До < {datetime}" но проблема в том что там есть ещё один цвет серый он и его показывает

Comment: @Павел покажите скриншотом как выглядит текущий результат

Comment: @Ev_Hyper добавил скрин т.е он убирает все белые и жёлтые значения а серые и красные остаются